# .NET - Add file into subfolder, then that subfolder into rootfolder, then rootfolder into ZIP

Tags: c#, .net, zip, directory

I have `fileName` and `contentBytes`, that should be added into `subfolder`, then `subfolder` should be added into `rootfolder`, and then `rootfolder` should be added into `ZIP`.

What I have at the moment is (where `zip` is ):

```
using (var zip = ZipHelper.Initialize()) {
   var subfolder= "Prefix" + fileName;
   zip.AddEntry(subfolder, contentBytes);
}
```

I need to add one more level into this structure:

```
- contentBytes into subfolder
- subfolder into rootfolder and then:
- zip.AddEntry(rootfolder , subfolderContent);
```

Comment: Take a look at [`File.Move()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Directory.Move()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (or their [`.Copy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx) couterparts).

Comment: @RufusL are you sure the OS implementation knows how to handle creating the Zip file and its content?

Comment: @rene Maybe I misunderstood the question. I meant to do the copy/move before zipping. [`ZipArchive.CreateEntry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158346(v=vs.110).aspx) can be used to add to an existing .zip file.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I don't think the duplicate is awesome, so I won't hammer it.

Comment: Boys, I should have: `rootfolder/folder/file.ext` inside `zip`.